# Can I use a .php picture as iconUrl?

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I would like to make the leaflet markers with PHP. I made a file marker.php and now I like to use it in leaflet.

I thought the solution is:

```js
var icon = L.icon({iconUrl: 'markers/marker.php?color=ffffff'});
```

The .php replies a .png file. But in leaflet I got an image-not-found picture.

The .php works correctly if I ask for it with:

```html
<img src="markers/marker.php?color=ffffff" />
```

What am I doing wrong.

And how to solve the problem? Kyon wrote you have to fetch. But how?

Comment: This is because of `leaflet` afaik. The icon method wants an image link. It doesn't resolve images automatically, so you have to `fetch` the image first and then put into the library.

Comment: can you trick it by using `?color=ffffff&icon.png` to get a "file extension" on the end of the url?

Comment: @Kyon how can I fetch the image and put it in a library. It says me nothing.